# how to include library project in Jacoco coverage report?

Tags: android, code-coverage, libraries, jacoco

Already included with `mainSrc`:

root > src > main > java

Library I want to include (`myLibrarySrc`):

root > libraries > myLibrary > src > main > java

My attempt inside `task jacocoTestReport`:

```
def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"
def myLibrarySrc = [project.file("libraries/myLibrary"), "/src/main/java"]

sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc], librarySrc)
```

I haven't been able to log output so I'm kind of flying blind.

Comment: DId you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any updates? I also face the save problem.